# How do I fix this poorly designed double-rod towel rack?

Tags: bolts, terminology

Original question: How do I name/ describe this bolt so that I can search for and purchase it?

I have a troublesome towel rack that I’ve been fighting with, off and on, for several years. After much analysis it turns out to simply be a very poor design, allowing one of the hollow towel rods to fall to the floor.

Closely examining the design there are a pair of existing 1/2” 40-TPI #5 machine screws that I could replace with shoulder bolts, and securely attach to the troublesome rod with set screws, but I have no idea how to search for a shoulder bolt with a head that will accept (hopefully pre-drilled and pre-tapped) set screws perpendicular to the bolt threads. While a single set screw on each bolt head would be ideal, I could need up to three, to ensure the rod is properly held in place. The “shoulder part” of the new bolt will need to be at least an additional 1/2”-3/4” long, on top on the 1/2” threaded part.

How do I describe and search for the bolt I need? How likely am I to find exactly what I’m looking for? If what I’m looking for isn’t readily available, what modifications do you recommend I make to this proposed design?

Thank you in advance!

[image: The fully assembled towel rack] The fully assembled towel rack. (The sides rotate apart letting the bottom rod fall.)

[image: One of the screws to be replaced, the parts it fits together with, and inside the hollow rod.]
One of the screws to be replaced, the parts it fits together with, and inside the hollow rod.

[image: close up of the troublesome joint assembled]
close up of the troublesome joint assembled.
(I will need a “shoulder bolt” to extend through the funnel, and into the rod, where I can drill holes for the set screw.)

Comment: Show a couple of pictures then it may be easy to come up with suggestions. But taking a bolt and drilling and tapping a thread is one possibility - depending mainly on skill and tools.

Comment: please post a picture of the towel rack and the problem area

Comment: Are you sure you aren’t throwing good labor after bad, trying to save a flimsy piece of imported junk?  It doesn’t sound like it was very well built in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure that a ton of epoxy wouldn't keep everything from rotating and falling off?

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica - Yes, it’s probably a piece of junk, but, as I didn’t choose it, it’s probably better that I get it working than replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get a long threaded bar cut to length to use the existing threads in the end brackets.

Seems to be the simplest option and only needs cutting to length.

Comment: I like the simplicity of the solution (or at least part of me does). The rod actually has some plastic obstructions in it, but they seem to be easily pushed down. I need to make sure I can actually push these out the other end. I own a hack saw, but would prefer someone machine cut it, then ship it to me. I need to see if I can find a vendor that would do this. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, don’t even get *that* bespoke.  Just use threaded rod and 2 couplers.  Couplers are hex shaped rods with an internal passage threaded the same.  So inside the pipe you go machine screw -> coupler -> threaded rod -> coupler -> machine screw.  Done and dusted.  You only need to do it on the lower one.  The threaded rod only needs to be coarsely to length; you can do that with a hacksaw or Dremel.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica - yes... I was going back and forth between a solid cut rod, and what you suggested. Either way I need to either push the plastic barriers out the other end of the rod, or drill through them. (I suspect I can simply force them out the other end: They already recede when pushed.)

Comment: FYI, I anticipate marking this the accepted answer when I successfully use it to repair the towel rack.

Comment: You know that saying about bringing a knife to a gun fight? Well, I learned the hard way you don’t measure screw diameter or thread pitch with a ruler. After purchasing a steel dial caliper, I believe I have either a 1/2” #7-27 TPI or a 13mm M3.8-.95 machine screw but neither appear to be standard sizes. Also, the length of the threaded bar you suggested that I use, I’ve measured to be 25.5”, and, as you suggested, I expect to need to cut that to length, if that matters.

Comment: After measuring repeatedly with my caliper, and with a screw gauge... and looking into screw tolerances, I finally came to the conclusion that I had a #8-32TPI screw... I bought the correct threaded rod, cut it to length, installed it, and it worked like a charm... thank you!

Comment: Looks perfect, good job.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn’t post any “after” photos yet, (I had planned to paint the wall behind it first), but it really doesn’t LOOK any different... it just doesn’t fall apart any more.